# Intel Haxm has been installed and running, but the Android Studio can't recognize it

Tags: flutter, android-studio, intel

I'm not being able to set up the Android Studio(hedgehog version) because in the virtual device manager, it is displaying the notification 'Intel HAXM not installed' when i have installed Intel HAXM on my system and it is even running properly in the system, which i have confirmed through command prompt. I have tried a lot of methods to solve it but haven't found an apt solution. What can i do that will best solve this problem?

I have tried a lot of methods referring to the intel website as well as from Youtube but i'm still stuck in this problem. Please suggest me a method so that i can setup my android studio and get to work. Thanks.

Comment: Please change the `android` tag to `android studio`.